# Cache-Control for ads.txt, robots.txt and sitemap.xml files that are generated dynamically

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt, cache, cdn, cache-control

I have some "static files" that I build on the fly, because they are generated dynamically.

```
ads.txt
robots.txt
sitemap.xml
```

What is the ideal `Cache-Control` for those files? PS: My server is behind a CDN.

Can I leave them as `private` or should I go with `no-store`?

I guess the result would be the same, because neither will be cached by the CDN and `private` enforces validation any way.

Comment: I'm not sure that it matters.  Google only fetches `robots.txt` once per day no matter what your cache control headers are set to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand you want to use Cache-Control private/no-store because you don't want the CDN to cache an outdated version of those files. However, not caching these files (i.e. all requests go back to your origin) might make your server vulnerable to a DDOS attack.

Leverage the CDN for what it does best. Unless these files change several times in the hour, I suggest caching them for at least a minute if not more.

Cheers.

Comment: That's a good point. I haven't thought of it like that. Thank you.